# On the relation between the asymptotics of a Dirichlet series' coefficients and the series' analytic continuability

Tags: nt.number-theory, cv.complex-variables, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

There is a wonderful series of articles by Flajolet et. al. about Mellin Transforms and the asymptotic analysis of generating functions. In particular, on page 45 of the article [Mellin Transforms and Asymptotics: Harmonic Sums](http://algo.inria.fr/flajolet/Publications/mellin-harm.pdf), they state the following result:

> Proposition 6 (Growth of Special Dirichlet Series): Let $\lambda_{k}$
>   and $\mu_{k}$ admit asymptotic expansions in descending powers of $k$
>   as
>   $$\lambda_{k}\sim\sum_{r=0}^{\infty}\frac{a_{r}}{k^{\alpha_{r}}}$$
>   $$\mu_{k}\sim k^{w}\left(1+\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{b_{r}}{k^{\beta_{r}}}\right)$$
>   Then the Dirichlet series $\sum_{k}\lambda_{k}\mu_{k}^{-s}$ can be
>   continued to a meromorphic function $\Lambda\left(s\right)$ in the
>   whole of the complex plane.

Now, let $V$ be an arbitrary set of infinitely many positive integers, and let: $$\zeta_{V}\left(s\right)\overset{\textrm{def}}{=}\sum_{v\in V}\frac{1}{v^{s}}$$

Enumerating the elements of $V$ in increasing order as $v_{1},v_{2},\ldots$, recall that one way of defining the natural density of $V$ (denoted $d\left(V\right))$ is: $$d\left(V\right)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{n}{v_{n}}$$ In the case where $d\left(V\right)$ exists and is positive, this gives the asymptotic $d\left(V\right)v_{n}\sim n$. As such, for: $$\frac{\zeta_{V}\left(s\right)}{\left(d\left(V\right)\right)^{s}}=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(d\left(V\right)v_{n}\right)^{s}}$$ I have that $$\lambda_{k}=1$$ and $$\mu_{k}=d\left(V\right)v_{k}\sim k$$ which is obtained by taking:$$\mu_{k}\sim k^{w}\left(1+\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}\frac{b_{r}}{k^{\beta_{r}}}\right)$$ setting $w=1$, and letting all the $b_{r}$s be $0$. Hence, unless I am mistaken, Proposition 6 implies that $\zeta_{V}\left(s\right)$ extends to a meromorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$ whenever $V$ has positive natural density.

However, consider the following. Let $\mathbb{P}$ denote the set of prime numbers. Then, $\zeta_{\mathbb{P}}\left(s\right)$ is the so-called Prime Zeta Function, which is known to have a natural boundary on the imaginary axis. On the other hand, since $d\left(\mathbb{P}\right)=0$, it follows that $\mathbb{N}/\mathbb{P}$ has a well-defined natural density of $1$, and thus, by Proposition 6, that $\zeta_{\mathbb{N}/\mathbb{P}}\left(s\right)$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$. However, since I can write:$$\zeta_{\mathbb{P}}\left(s\right)=\zeta\left(s\right)-\zeta_{\mathbb{N}\backslash\mathbb{P}}\left(s\right)$$ it follows that $\zeta_{\mathbb{P}}\left(s\right)$ is the difference of two meromorphic functions, which forces $\zeta_{\mathbb{P}}\left(s\right)$ to be meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$, which is obviously not correct.

So, where's the error, and how (if at all) can it be rectified? In particular, when, if ever, does the existence of $d\left(V\right)$ imply that $\zeta_{V}\left(s\right)$ is meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Proposition 6 does not imply that if $V$ has positive natural density then $\zeta_V(s)$ extends to a meromorphic function. This is because the density assumption is much weaker than the assumptions in Proposition 6. Indeed, if the elements of $V$ are $v_1<v_2<\dotsb$, then the density assumption says that $v_k$ is asymptotically a constant times $k$, while Proposition 6 requires a full asymptotic expansion of $v_k$ in descending powers of $k$. The latter means that, for any nonnegative integer $R$, there are exponents $w_1>w_2>\dotsb>w_R$ and coefficients $c_1,c_2,\dotsc,c_R\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$v_k=c_1 k^{w_1}+c_2 k^{w_2}+\dotsb+c_{R-1}k^{w_{R-1}}+(c_R+o(1))k^{w_R}.$$
The density assumption implies that we have such a relation for $R=1$, namely $w_1=1$ and $c_1=1/d(V)$ work, but it does not imply the relation for $R=2$. And in fact, for the sequence of non-primes $\mathbb{N}\setminus\mathbb{P}$, the above approximation only holds for $R=1$.

Comment: can you check if I didn't miss some point

Comment: @reuns: I trust what you write. Note also that the validity of Prop. 6 is not an issue, the quoted paper sketches the proof. The OP seems to have mixed up the terms "is asymptotic to" and "has asymptotic expansion", and this caused the confusion.

Comment: @GH: See, this is why I dislike people who sketch proofs and speak sketchily of things. ;)

Comment: Done. You're welcome. I already am very well aware of the content you explained. It's *incredibly* frustrating to get tripped up simply because of other people's careless failures to actually *say what they mean*, rather than mere *mean what they say*.

Comment: @MCS: I think you are too hard on the authors. They do say "asymptotic expansion", and the definition of this notion is standard: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_expansion#Formal_definition

Comment: The definition of "~" I most commonly use is the one given in section 8.3 of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

This is one of the things I *hate* about asymptotic analysis: a given relational symbol might mean different things, depending on the context.

But, yes, I am hard to please. For example, you'll never catch me writing "isomorphism" without specifying the particular type of isomorphism (locally compact abelian group, hilbert space, non-commutative ring, etc.). I eagerly await the day the rest of the world decides to join me in my loft of undue clarity. :)

Comment: @MCS: I agree that the notation $\sim$ is ambiguous, but in this article the words "asymptotic expansion" should clarify the meaning. At any rate, take it easy!

Comment: @GH: Good news! I found a result on Dirichlet series that lets me conclude that, as long as $V$ has a well-defined natural density, its zeta function cannot have a natural boundary on any vertical line with positive real part. The proof and requisite citation are given below. :)

Comment: @MCS: If you pick a random subset $V\subset\mathbb{N}$ such that, for each $v\in\mathbb{N}$, the event $v\in V$ occurs with probability $1/2$, and these events are independent of each other, then with probability $1$ the following holds: $V$ has natural density $1/2$, the function $\zeta_V(s)-\frac{1/2}{s-1}$ is holomorphic for $\Re(s)>1/2$ but has $\Re s=1/2$ as a natural boundary. This follows from a result of Kahane (1973), see https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k6236938x/f35.image

Answer (score 5):

> $$F(s)=\sum_{k}\lambda_{k}\mu_{k}^{-s}$$ extends meromorphically with finitely many poles in each strip because $$\Gamma(s)F(s)= \int_0^\infty f(t)t^{s-1}dt, \qquad f(t)=\sum_{k}\lambda_{k} e^{-t \mu_{k}}$$ where $f$ has an expansion in powers of $t$ near $0$ which makes clear the exact conditions you need for it to hold.

- The expansion $\mu_k= k^{w}\left(1+\sum_{r\le R}b_{r}k^{-\beta_r} + o(k^{-\beta_R})\right)$  leads to (expanding the $\exp$) $$e^{-\mu_k t}= e^{-k^wt} \exp(-  \sum_{r\le R} b_r k^{(w-\beta_r) t}) (1+o(k^{-\beta_R})) \\= e^{-k^wt} \sum_{j\le J} c_j t^{d_j} k^{e_j}+ o(t^{d_J}k^{-e_j} e^{-k^wt})$$
- together with the expansion $\lambda_k = \sum_{r \le R} a_r k^{-\alpha_r} + o(k^{-\alpha_R})$ it leads to $$f(t) = \sum_{l\le L} C_l t^{D_l} \sum_k k^{E_l} e^{-k^wt}+ o(t^{d_L} \sum_k k^{e_L} e^{-k^wt})$$

For every $r$, for $L$ large enough we have $t^{d_L} \sum_k k^{e_L} e^{-k^wt} = o(t^r)$ so the error term won't be a problem.

And from our knowledge of $\Gamma(s) \zeta(Bs+C)$, of Mellin inversion and the residue and Tauberian theorem we know that  $\sum_k k^{E_l} e^{-k^wt}$ has an expansion in powers of $t$.

Thus so does $f$ $$f(t) = \sum_{m \le M} u_m t^{v_m} + o(t^{v_M}), \qquad v_m \to \infty$$ from which we have our meromorphic continuation to $\Re(s) > -v_M$ $$\Gamma(s)F(s)= \int_0^\infty (f(t)-\sum_{m \le M} u_m t^{v_m} 1_{t < 1})t^{s-1}dt+ \sum_{m \le M}\frac{u_m }{s+v_m}$$